# How do i see if a key is pressed down using Pynput in Python?

Tags: python, pynput

I want to (by using Pynput in Python) see if a key is pressed down. For example:
while True:
    if #key alt is pressed down:
        print("Alt is pressed down")

Comment: Its in the docs... https://pypi.org/project/pynput/ , pynput.keyboard.Listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install pynput in python use following command

```
pip install pynput
```

And to check if a key **alt** is pressed below is my code, for more details refer to the [link](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html)

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Will this work if the key is pressed before the script is run ?